# Mongoose custom sort with date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I retrieve data with a custom sort in `Mongoose`?
There is a job starting date that needs to be sorted by the month and year, but currently this script is only sorting from December to January.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Job.find()
    .sort({ from: -1 })
    .then(jobs => res.json(jobs))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
});
```

The problem is in the sort; values for *from* is like `12.2018`, `06.2019`, `03.2020`, `11.2009` and so on.

I want to sort these results first from the year (which is after the dot) and then sort from the months. I cannot currently change how the data is set and it's stored as a `String` in the model Schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use aggregation framework to first transform your string to a valid date by

- [$spliting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) it,
- [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) parts from string to int
- and using [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/),

then you sort and finally remove created field.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          year: {
            $convert: {
              input: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $split: [
                      "$from",
                      "."
                    ]
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              to: "int"
            }
          },
          month: {
            $convert: {
              input: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $split: [
                      "$from",
                      "."
                    ]
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              to: "int"
            }
          },

        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      date: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: 0
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9e2fxJ4Iedm)

Comment: Where to put this code into? Into the router.get or in the axios call which I use in the React componentDidMount function.

Comment: don't jknow React, but here aggregate in another mongodb function, like 'find' or 'update'. So Job.aggregate(...) must be the right place